# Prevent to go another page until form is submitted

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my project I have a functionality that whenever there is a new user created and he logs in into the account, he must first change the password.

So if user is new I show ChangePassowrd screen first after login. Menu has only ChangePassowrd and LogOut option existed.

Now if suppose he enter some url of website which is accessible only after user do password change, it is not allowed. Do anyone know how I can implement it? I know widnow.unload but it doesn't work if url is direct pasted. 
In server side, I have a BaseController which call before any controller(but after controller's constructor called) for initialization. I tried to change RouteData.Values but it didn't work. it throws error 404 not found. Code is as below:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
  if (requestContext != null)
  {
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    if (Convert.ToString(requestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserType"]) == "3")
    {
      requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Login";
      requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "ChangePassword";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's not possible in client side. user simply can open new tab past url so you have to do server side checking.

Comment: you cannot use only  controller code? What about rest of files? If you want to do it only on frontend, it is not possible. You have to use server side.

Comment: @mo.esmp ok. But how I can achieve it at server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after all try, I resolve it with following code in BaseController: I think this is the simpler version.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  if (filterContext != null)
  {
    if (Session["UserType"] != null && Convert.ToString(Session["UserType"]) == "3") // New User
    {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "ChangePassword", controller = "Login" }));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new property in the user model, meaning expanding the asp.net identity model and having this new property be something like public bool passwordChanged { get; set;}
Check this property where access should not be allowed unless password is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in that way.

In `AppStart/FilterConfig.cs` file add

```
filters.Add(new ChangePasswordRequiredActionFilter());
```

Now, you have to add implementation for that filter. You can do it in `global.asax` file, or anywhere you want:

```
public class ChangePasswordRequiredActionFilter: IActionFilter
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Now you have to put your custom logic here, this is example:

            User user = ourService.GetUser(blablabla);
            if (user != null && !user.ChangePassword)
            {

                if (currentUrl != "/Account/ChangePassword" && currentUrl != "/Account/LogOff")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/ChangePassword");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This solution ensures that you will check your conditions on every user request to server.

Comment: I cant get session here.

Comment: what session? You don't use session here. You just operate on `Request` system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the user state to "Not logged in" until after the user has both logged in and changed the password.

If this question is specific to some technology, it's not obvious from the way the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality which u want u have to make a custom filter in ur webapp like one given below...

```
 public class ChangePasswordAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
            //Check user has changed password or not 
             if(--yes--){ nothing to do }
             else{ GoToChangePasswordPage(filterContext); }
             return;
    }

    private static void GoToChangePasswordPage(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
              new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "controller", "Login" }, 
                { "action", "ChangePassword" } 
            });
    }
 }
```

For more help how to build a custom filter in asp.net mvc visit..
1.)http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=976

2.)http://sampathloku.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-action-filter-for.html